# Azure application gateway with app service - https listener using app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

In Azure I've an application gateway connected with a backend-pool with an Azure app service. This Azure app service accepts http and https traffic.

I added an http listener and created a rule to redirect http traffic to backend pool. This is working fine.

However I would like to do the same with https protocol. But when I'm trying to add the https listener I'm requested to add the pfx certificate. This is expected obviously. But in this case I would like to redirect the https traffic to the Azure App Service which has configured https access, and there is no way (that I know) to export Azure App Service certificate.

Do you know if there is a way to redirect https traffic on an application gateway to an Azure App Service without the certificate "trusting" only on Azure App Service?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Would it help you if you had an exported copy of your app service certificate? If so, you can do so by going to portal.azure.com> app service certs> select your cert> select the export certificate blade > select open key vault secret> select the current version of your cert> select "download as a certificate.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, problem here is that I have a *.azurewebsites certificate and those, as far as I know, are not exportable on the way you mentioned.